# How to declare a two variable from the values of foreach loop

Tags: php

I have two rows that came from mysql data base.

```
$data = $this->Common_model->get_records('my_team','*',array('users_id'=>$user_id,'tittle_id'=>$tittle_id));

foreach ($data as  $value) 
{
    var_dump($value);
}
```

when I print a $value my output below
Output:

```
object(stdClass)#22 (5) 
{ 
 ["my_team_id"]=> string(1) "15" 
 ["users_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
 ["tittle_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
 ["my_team_name"]=> string(10) "Ram Sports Club" 
}

object(stdClass)#23 (5) 
{ 
 ["my_team_id"]=> string(1) "16" 
 ["users_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
 ["tittle_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
 ["my_team_name"]=> string(20) "Royal Victoriens club"  
}
```

now my need is how can I get my_team_id and place to different variables, Example below

```
$team_a = 15;
$tema_b = 16;
```

how can declare this, please help me

Comment: WHile that is possible, it does not make a great deal of sense. Think ahead and work out what you want to do with this information

Comment: Simple answer `$team_a = $value[0]->my_team_id;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$data` is an array. What you can do is the following:

```
$team_a = $data[0]['my_team_id'];
$team_b = $data[1]['my_team_id'];
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
That's not workout

Comment: Do you have any Getter for your stdClass? If so you could use those instead.